# Python referring to an item in a list from another list

Tags: python, list, pass-by-reference

I have a list of variables (listA) from from another list (listB). The problem I am having is that the items from listB are being passed by value to listA rather than by reference. Is there anyway I can access the the object in listB after having put its value in listA?

For example:

```
listB = [1,2,3,4,5]
listA = [listB[0], listB[1]]
listA[0] = 0
```

this makes listA equal to [0, 2], and leaves listB unchanged. I would like to modify listB so that it becomes [0,2,3,4,5].

I have of course come up with a solution to this, but its ugly, and I was wondering if there was an elegant way of doing this.

Comment: You can't. If you'd like help deuglifying a piece of code: Post it at http://codereview.stackexchange.com. Somebody there will point out a more elegant solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in python is a reference. After all those statements are executed, `listB[1]` and `listA[1]` are *literally* the same object. (you can check, by calling `id(listB[1])` and `id(listA[1])`.

The reason `listA[0]` and `listB[0]` are different is merely because you put a different reference into that spot.

Judging from your description, you don't want to a `listA` that stores references to the objects in `listB`. What you want is a `listA` that is a *view* of `listB`. I believe you have only two options:

- Create a special sequence that internally stores a reference to `listA`, and whose `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods perform lookups into `listA` when invoked.
- Create special a special reference types that contains something like a "sequence and index". Put these references into `listA`. But, to modify `listB` through `listA`, you'll have to invoke some sort of "get" and "set" members of these reference objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. First of all integers are immutable and they don't work like integers in C/C++. You can't get pointer/reference to an integer and then change it (I mean you can, you always have a reference, but it is usually reference to a single object; check this `x = 1; y = 1; print id(x), id(y)`; id values should be the same and they are memory addresses). What you can do is get index of elements in listB and change the list, e.g.:

```
listA = [0, 1]
listB[listA[0]] = 0
```

But probably you are trying to do something you are not supposed to do, because Python works differently than C++. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a data matrix of size n, and I am checking every possible 2x2 subsets of that matrix. I then store the 4 values from that 2x2 subset in a list and check their value. Based on what the contents of that 2x2 subset is, I have to modify the original data matrix that is of size n.

I thought the same thing, to store the indices of the original matrix that the 2x2 matrix holds, but that would have required more complicated data types and/or a less elegant solution. Since I am trying to improve my python programming skills, I was wondering if there was a pythonian/elegant of doing this.

Comment: For such things I believe you should use NumPy or SciPy, which are python libraries created exactly for this. If you want to use pure python your best choice is to remember indices of submatrices and change values in the list. Simply instead of storing values of a submatrix store left, top corner of this submatrix and change values in the original table. Maybe you could present a short snippet in C or C++ (but seriously, keep it short) and we can try to come up with code in Python, that does the same.

Comment: @AmeerOpat, I don't have a real clear idea on what you are doing, but I'd suggest thinking about creating a new matrix rather then modifying the existing one. That usually produces a more pythonic solution. (As I mentioned above, better feedback available if you post on code review)